# Entity Framework - Many to Many - Not Saving

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many

I have two objects (Object A and Object B).  They have a many to many relationship.

I am using a generic data access layer that does this:

```
public virtual void Save(params T[] items)
{
  var keyName = GetIdKeyName<T>();

  foreach (T item in items.Where(GetByIdPredicate<T>(0, keyName).Compile()))
  {
    db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;
  }

  foreach (T item in items.Where(GetByIdPredicate<T>(0, keyName, ExpressionType.NotEqual).Compile()))
  {
    db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
  }

  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I want to save the relationship between Object A and Object B.  If I do:

```
 ObjectA.ObjectBs.Add(ObjectB)
 dataAccess.Save(ObjectA)
```

The many to many relationship is generated, but it creates a new ObjectB.  I thought this was because it didn't have an updated entitystate, so I tried:

```
dataAccess.Save(ObjectB)
ObjectA.ObjectBs.Add(ObjectB)
dataAccess.Save(ObjectA)
```

But the same thing happens.  Any ideas as to how I can get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue.  I was creating a data access instance per object.  So when DataAccess was saving, it didn't know about DataAccess.  I changed the access layer so the methods take in a type and all is well.